# assigning variable inside a library function

Tags: r

I am trying to create a `r` library. When I create and call a function that does some assignment from outside of the library, it works (CASE A) but not when I call it from within the library (CASE B).

**For example:**

```
test<- function(){
  for(f in list.files()){

    print(f)

    dt <- read.csv(f, nrows=1, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
    nm <- strsplit(f,".")[[1]][1]

    assign(paste0(nm,"_dim"), dt)
  }
}
```

I understand that in CASE A, the `assign` just go to the global environment but I am not sure what happens in CASE B.

Ideally I don't want to *pollute* the global environment with a large number of variables that will only be used with the package such that using 
`assign(paste0(nm,"_dim"), dt, envir = globalenv())` is my last option.

I naively tried to do `assign(paste0(nm,"_dim"), dt, envir = as.environment("package:mypackagename"))` but I get the `cannot add bindings to a locked environment` error

Any ideas?

Comment: It might be a little hard to give a good answer here, because I think opinions will gravitate toward saying that you simply shouldn't be doing this at all inside a package (using `assign` in an analogous way that you might otherwise). But it's hard to say what you _should_ do without knowing exactly why you're doing this and what you're actually trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: @joran I would tend to agree with you: libraries/packages should just be functions to remain true to the functional aspect of `r`. However, in my case, I have over 1000 variables that are only used internally to the package. It would make the user experience better if they are shielded from the complexity of the internal process. I found a section regarding `package state` from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html and will just use that for now.

Comment: Haven't thought much about whether this is a good or bad idea, but you could potentially create a new environment when the package is loaded and then use it. Seems similar to the package state from that link...

Comment: You can't really create new variables in your package environment. You could define an environment that you don't export from your package, but functions defined in your package could access that environment and store variables there. Kind of similar to how [ggplot tracks the last plot](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/1c09bae2aa24320bcb4891c664cccc16efc86a8a/R/plot-last.r)

Comment: Dang it, @MrFlick, I learned something again: `last_plot()`. Never new it was there. Kinda handy, I actually could have used it today, never thought to look for it (instead I just re-ran the code that generated it the first time). Thanks for the link.